# Download an image using the least amount of memory

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I'm developing an app for WP8. In a `ScheduledTaskAgent` I need to download an image from internet, save it to storage, after that I load the same image and do some processing. I am facing the dreaded `OutOfMemoryException`. If I remove the "download and save image" (using an already saved image) part, it all works. If I just download and save, it all works. Maybe in the first schedule I can save it, in the second process. But I do not understand where or why my download image is holding memory so, can anyone suggest me a better way to do this? Here is my actual code:

```
    private async Task GetImage(string url)
    {
        using (var http = new HttpClient())
        {
            var clientResponse = await http.GetByteArrayAsync(url);

            var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(lockFilename, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            using (var fs = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                var outStream = fs.GetOutputStreamAt(0);
                using (var dataWriter = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter(outStream))
                {
                    dataWriter.WriteBytes(clientResponse);
                    await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
                    dataWriter.DetachStream();
                    await outStream.FlushAsync();
                    outStream.Dispose(); 
                    fs.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to stream it down.. not download the whole thing in bulk.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download/Stream file from URL - asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596747/download-stream-file-from-url-asp-net)

Comment: Why are you calling `Dispose` and using `using`. And why are you calling `Dispose` instead of using `using`?

Comment: Have you tried [`Stream.CopyToAsync(Stream)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh159084.aspx "Stream.CopyToAsync Method (Stream)")?

Comment: Simon, thank you for your suggestion - this indeed was the right way. I can load all the image in memory and it works, the problem is that .net did not releases all that used memory when I wanted... but streaming it (like is suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140733/download-image-in-windows-phone-8) worked.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing, maybe it can be a duplicate answer but the question are different. I would not get there from where I was....

Comment: @PauloMorgado I tried all combinations of using and disposing, to see if it made a difference - it did not.

Comment: @Leo, I wouldn't expect it to. That's why I posted as a separate comment.

Answer (score 0):

By using HttpClient.GetStreamAsync you will get access directly to the network stream and you can copy that stream to the filestream.  This should reduce the memory consumption.